# facebook chat using asmack on android with the new access token

Tags: android, facebook

I have a FB chat client developed for Android. I've been using facebook android-sdk to obtain the access token from a user. Using asmack, user was logged into the chat. Token was in the form: 226409362971500|3b29bc82baa7901a9baca042.4-72793766|9eb417f06fc376897222938295a0dd0c The code I used was:

```
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", SASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", 0);
xmpp.connect();
xmpp.login("226409362971500", "3b29bc82baa7901a9fbaca042.4-72793766|9eb417f06fc376897222938295a0dd0c", "Application");
```

Now it seems that Facebook has changed the token format. I have tried logging in with the old token, but I always get XMPPException. I've tried logging in with the new access token:

`xmpp.login(token, "Application")`,
but still no luck.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research (php example on the [official FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) is really good), I came to a following conclusion:
 1. xmpp connection must use ssl
 2. in a response, `session_key` must be replaced with `access_token`

In short:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
xmpp.connect();
xmpp.login(appSecret, accessToken, "Application");
```

`SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism` is my class which extends from `org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism`

Comment: what are the values of appSecret, accessToken: and where i have to use my Uname and Password..

Comment: if I remember correctly, you get appSecret when you register your app with facebook. accessToken is obtained via Android Facebook SDK, when user grants permission for your app.

Comment: not yet Maggie, help me on this....this is the Question --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook

Comment: Thank you for your help, but could you please tell me more about SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism? Thank you